# Runge-Kutta curve fitting extremely slow

Tags: curve-fitting, numerical-integration, non-linear-regression, runge-kutta

I am currently trying to do a regression of a function calculated via a RK4 method performed on a non-linear Volterra integral of the second kind. The problem I found is that the code is extremely slow, for 1 call of the curve_fit function (fitt), it takes about 30-40 minute to generate a data. Overall, there will be a lot of calls to fitt before the parameters are determined, this takes more than 6 hours to run. Is there anyway to optimize this code? Thanks in advance!

```
from scipy.special import gamma
from ml_internal import LTInversion
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit , fsolve
from scipy.misc import derivative
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from math import comb , factorial
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Gets the data

df = pd.read_excel('D:\\CoMat\\Fractional_fit\\optimized\\data_optimized.xlsx')

skipTime = 1
skipIndex = df[df['Time']== skipTime].index.values[0]

xls = pd.read_excel('D:\\CoMat\\Fractional_fit\\optimized\\data_optimized.xlsx',skiprows=np.arange(1,skipIndex+1,1))

timeDF = xls['Time']
tempDF = xls['Temp']

taDF = xls['Ta']

timeDF = timeDF - timeDF[0]
tempDF = tempDF + 273.15

t0 = tempDF[0]
ta = sum(taDF)/len(taDF)

ta = ta + 273.15
###########################################

#Spliting into intervals
h = 0.05
a = 0
b = timeDF[len(timeDF)-1]
N = int(np.round((b-a)/h))

#Each xi
def xidx(index):
    return a + h*index

#Function in the image are written here.

def gx(t,lamda,alpha):
    return t0 * ml(lamda*(t**alpha),alpha)
gx = np.vectorize(gx)

def kernel(t,s,rad,lamda,alpha,beta):
    if t == s:
        return 0
    return (t-s)**(alpha-1) * ml_(lamda*((t-s)**alpha),alpha,alpha,1) * (beta*(rad**4) - beta*(ta**4) - lamda*ta)
kernel = np.vectorize(kernel)

############################
# The problem is here!!!!!!
def fx(x,n,lamda,alpha,beta):
    ans = gx(x,lamda,alpha)
    for j in range(n):
        ans += (h/6)*(kernel(x,xidx(j),f0[j],lamda,alpha,beta) + 2*kernel(x,xidx(j+1/2),f1[j],lamda,alpha,beta) + 2*kernel(x,xidx(j+1/2),f2[j],lamda,alpha,beta) + kernel(x,xidx(j+1),f3[j],lamda,alpha,beta))
    return ans

#########################
f0 = np.zeros(N+1)
f0[0] = t0
f1 = np.zeros(N+1)
f2 = np.zeros(N+1)
f3 = np.zeros(N+1)
F = np.zeros((3,N+1))

def fitt(xvalue,lamda,alpha,beta):
    global f0,f1,f2,f3,F
    n = int(np.round(xvalue/h))
    f1[n] = fx(xidx(n) + 1/2,n,lamda,alpha,beta) + (h/2)*kernel(xidx(n + 1/2),xidx(n),f0[n],lamda,alpha,beta)
    f2[n] = fx(xidx(n + 1/2),n,lamda,alpha,beta)
    f3[n] = fx(xidx(n+1),n,lamda,alpha,beta) + h*kernel(xidx(n+1),xidx(n+1/2),f2[n],lamda,alpha,beta)
    if n+1 <= N:
        f0[n+1] = fx(xidx(n+1),n,lamda,alpha,beta) + (h/6)*(kernel(xidx(n+1),xidx(n),f0[n],lamda,alpha,beta) + 2*kernel(xidx(n+1),xidx(n+1/2),f1[n],lamda,alpha,beta) + 2*kernel(xidx(n+1),xidx(n+1/2),f2[n],lamda,alpha,beta) + kernel(xidx(n+1),xidx(n+1),f3[n],lamda,alpha,beta))
    

    if(xvalue == timeDF[len(timeDF) - 1]):
        print(f0[n],n)
        returnValue = f0[n]
        f0 = np.zeros(N+1)
        f0[0] = t0
        f1 = np.zeros(N+1)
        f2 = np.zeros(N+1)
        f3 = np.zeros(N+1)
        return returnValue

    print(f0[n],n)
    return f0[n]

fitt = np.vectorize(fitt)

#Fitting, plotting and giving (Adj) R-squared
popt , pcov = curve_fit(fitt,timeDF,tempDF,p0=(-0.1317,0.95,-1e-11),bounds=((-np.inf,0,-np.inf),(0,1,0)))
print(popt)

y_fit = np.array(fitt(timeDF,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2]))

plt.scatter(timeDF,tempDF,color='ORANGE',marker='.',s=0.5)
plt.fill_between(timeDF,tempDF-0.5,tempDF+0.5,color='ORANGE', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(timeDF,y_fit,color='RED',linewidth=1)
plt.legend(["Experimental data", "Caputo fit"], loc ="upper right")
plt.xlabel("Time (min)")
plt.ylabel("Temperature (Kelvin)")
plt.show()
plt.close()

r2 = r2_score(tempDF,y_fit)
print(r2)

adjr2 = 1 - (1 - r2)*((len(xls)-1)/(len(xls)-3-1))
print(adjr2)
```

I already tried computing the values f0,f1,f2,f3 all at once, but the thing consuming the most time is Fn(x) which I haven't figured in out how to compute them all at once. If this is possible to compute at once, I think the program will run much faster. PS: ML,ML_ is a function from [https://github.com/khinsen/mittag-leffler.](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[image: Numerical solution of integral equations by L. M. Delves, J. Walsh - 1974] This is the function necesssary. Fn is the only one I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Function calls are expensive (xidx should be a fixed array). Vectorize is expensive, function call overhead and python loop inside. If you vectorize a function, then all functions inside get ever only scalar arguments, no need to vectorize these inner functions. What are `ml` and `ml_`?

Comment: They are Mittag-Leffler function as in https://github.com/khinsen/mittag-leffler. Thank you very much for your response! I will remove unnecessary vectorize calls and make xidx a fixed array. :)

Comment: F_n is a sequence of approximations to the solution function, it is exact (or at least final) on the interval [t[0],t[n]]. The step builds up the parameters for its continuation on [t[n],t[n+1]] to give F_{n+1}. One has f0[n] = F_n(t[n]) = f4[n-1]. /// Your computation is conceptually wrong, even if it might be correct in this specific case, that the timeDF values are actually separated by `h`. Otherwise you need to evaluate the final F_n at the points of timeDF.

Comment: There are some redundant computations of fx. /// You replicated the typing error of the cited article, it is always xidx(n+1/2) as function or with array x[n]+h/2.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, timeDF is actually seperated by h ( =0.05). Also, thanks for the notification of the typing error! You have helped me a lot! Thank you very much. Also, can you put this to an answer so I can accept and upvote? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two typing errors in the cited image. The combination of x_n and 1/2 is always meant to be the midpoint `x_{n+1/2} = x_n + h/2`. The second error is a duplication of x_{n+1/2} in the formula for f^{(4)}_n in its third term. The first error is probably producing errors that are large enough to make convergence complicated and any limit wrong for the intended problem.

---

In the Simpson/RK4 step, the 4 fx computations can be reduced to 2.

---

The F_n implement the left side of the integral equation

F(x) = g(x) + int(s=0 to x of K(x,s,f(s))

where the integral is approximated with the sample sequences f0,...,f3. Due to the structure of problem and algorithm F_n(x_n)=f^0_n = f^4_{n-1}.

---

Note that K(x,s,f) should be set to zero for s >= x. In the exact version of the equation these values "above the diagonal" are not used.

---

If an increase in accuracy is needed, for instance to avoid divergence where there is none in the exact solution, you can decrease the step site by a factor of 10 and then sub-sample the f^0_n sequence to produce the numerical guess for the given data. Other factors than 10 are of course also possible.

Comment: May I ask why K(x,s,f(s)) should be set to zero if s >= x? Is it only at when computing for F_n or in f0,f1,f2,f3 also? I'm so sorry to bother you again.

Comment: Generally. The integral from 0 to t can be replaced by an integral over the full interval of interest if the integrand is multiplied by the indicator function for the interval [0,t]. Now combine the kernel with this indicator function.